# Simple web downloader

Tags: c#, .net

The following programme is not giving me desired output:

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
string path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName,   myStringWebResource);
//Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName );
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" +path);
```

On moving to the location specified i.e.Application.StartupPath I find 'ms-banner.gif' file but with no data to display.

Why so?

Comment: I have tried several versions of it using .Downloaddata etc.but none of them are saving there at specified location

Comment: Have a read of http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

Comment: I already had been through there @Paul Zahra

Comment: That's suggesting me to modify my second parameter to DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, saveDisk) where:string saveDisk=@"E:\javed.txt"   but with an exception as output

Comment: Try another public file, contoso.com could be restricting access to it from somehow. To fool contoso.com you could try setting the webclient request headers: client.Headers["User-Agent"] =
     "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";
 client.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";